# What does _fpt_ stand for in semantic mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

In database I have two types of tables [based on their name]
Example:

```
1. smw_di_... => [semantic mediawiki data item => as I understood]

2. smw_fpt_... => [??]
```

And what is the key `s_id`

Does someone know?

It's important to me to understand the logic, because no books are available, no documentation...

Comment: I guess I found answer to my question, it's FixedPropertyTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FPT - Fixed Property Table

*Fixed Properties are properties that are user defined but intensively used in the wiki*

extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/src/SQLStore/PropertyTableInfoFetcher.php

```
private $fixedSpecialProperties = array(
        // property declarations
        '_TYPE', '_UNIT', '_CONV', '_PVAL', '_LIST', '_SERV',
        // query statistics (very frequently used)
        '_ASK', '_ASKDE', '_ASKSI', '_ASKFO', '_ASKST', '_ASKDU',
        // subproperties, classes, and instances
        '_SUBP', '_SUBC', '_INST',
        // redirects
        '_REDI',
        // has sub object
        '_SOBJ',
        // vocabulary import and URI assignments
        '_IMPO', '_URI',
        // Concepts
        '_CONC'
    );
```

*s_id => pointer [foreign key to smw_object_ids smw_id]*

*p_id => property id if it's not fixed DI*